# How to convert a custom date format in excel?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, formatting

I have the following date format: 
mmm-dd-yyyy (e.g. Sep-10-2013)

I need it to convert it to this one:
dd.mm.yy (e.g. 10.09.13)

Anybody an idea how what function might solve this issue?
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Dates are stored as numbers (`1 = 1-Jan-1900`), and displayed according to the cell format.  A formula cannot change the cell format, although it could create a text string that looks like what you want.  However, that text string cannot be used in any formulas that refer to that date (at least not easily).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1,DATEVALUE(MID(A1,5,2)&" "&LEFT(A1,3)&" "&RIGHT(A1,4)))
```

and then set your custom format in cell **B1**:

[image]

**NOTE:**

To change a date's format, we need to know if the input is a genuine Excel date or only a text string.  This formula does the testing for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your cells format of date.
Or use formula, (eg, A1 = `Sep-10-2013`)

```
=MONTH(A1)&"."&DAY(A1)&"."&RIGHT(YEAR(A1),2)
```